# Update Google Maps with GIS data

Tags: google-maps

Several county residents have been contacting our GIS office to find out why they are not receiving packages or why the delivery person gets lost finding their address.  I know it sounds like an odd question to as GIS, but it turns out thier packages are being delivered by UPS, FedEx, etc. All of them use Google Maps to locate an address in our county.  I checked a few of the addresses in question and they are either non-existent or in the wrong location.  I also found several subdivisions where not a single road is showing up in Google Maps either.  Now I know I can submit a "suggestion" to Google for them to update the map, but I really do not want to do this several hundred times to correct all the errors I have found so far.

Is there a way to upload GIS data from the county in order to update their maps? If so, is there an app, interface, or procedure available to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using Googles Geo Data Upload tool: https://support.google.com/mapcontentpartners/answer/9359673?hl=en#.